# Sys_Refcursor is null

Tags: oracle

I have this c# code

```
public static DataSet Get_Workflow_Def()
{
    OracleConnection conn = DatabaseHelper.getOracleConnection();

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    Log.Info("Opening connection");
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("CTS.GET_WORKFLOW_DEF", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_Dataset", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = 
    ParameterDirection.Output;

    Log.Info("Executing query");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dataset);
    conn.Close();

    return dataset;
}
```

Calling this procedure

```
    create or replace procedure CTS.GET_WORKFLOW_DEF(p_Dataset OUT 
    Sys_Refcursor)

    as

    begin
     Open p_Dataset For
     Select WKF_ID,
            WKF_WORKFLOW_ID,
            WKF_WORKFLOW_NAME,
            WKF_WORKFLOW_VERSION,
            WKF_WORKFLOW_SCHEMA
     FROM CTS.WKF_WORKFLOW_MASTER
     WHERE WKF_WORKFLOW_ACTIVE = '1'
     ORDER BY WKF_ID DESC;

    end GET_WORKFLOW_DEF;
```

If I execute the query I get the information I am looking for but the RefCursor is null. I'm an Oracle newb. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the RefCursor is null"?

Comment: you run your select statement alone and returns a record?

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem I needed to add this line before the da.fill(dataset); line and after I instantiated the OracleDataAdapter in my c# code

```
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBPullTable"].ToString());
```